# Certificate Pinning in Concurrent requests Swift

Tags: ios, swift, x509certificate, certificate-pinning

I'm writing an app in swift 5 that needs to connect to my server. I have the full certificate chain. i have implemented certificate pinning and i have a success connection when i have one request but it fail when multiple requests at the same time
why certificate pinning not work with multiple requests in the same time in swift?

Comment: Can you show the error messages or anything else that would help us understand better your issue?

Comment: the problem is when i have doing some parallels request, only request succeeded but the rest was canceled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i find the solution, so the issue is due to the allocation of the session, i have created a static variable session to void the allocation and it worked successfully